# codeigniter: send a multidimensional array from view to controller via ajax

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have a php multidimensional array:

```
$array[0] = array('Jack','jack@mail.com');
$array[1] = array('one'=>'test1','two'=>'test2'); //unknown data limit 
it could be 5 or 10 or 100 items consider the second array as purchased products.
```

I want to send this array $array to the controller from the view. I tried:

```
$newArray = json_encode($array);
$.post('<?=base_url()?>controller/function/<?=$newArray ?>').done(function (res) {
        alert(res);
    });
```

But I get a security error can't send '[' or '{' in a url. and when I just echo $array in the post it won't work becuase the result will be: "Array".

So the question now is how to send this multidimensional array from view to controller in codeigniter?

Comment: As a second argument of `$.post`

Comment: Works fine thanks. I'm still not familiar with codeigniter and tried this way without json_encode but didn't work. You can add it as an answer
$.post('<?=base_url()?>/controller/function',{t:<?=newArray?>})

Comment: You can answer your own question)

Answer (score 1):

add this code in your view

```
<script>
   var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(yourArray);
   var url="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/controller/show_json";
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     dataType: 'json',
     data: myJsonString,
     success: function(data){
             console.log(data); 
          }
      });
</script>
```

add this function on your controllers

```
function show_json()
{
   print_r($_POST);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.urlencode.php) (or [encodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) in javascript) in the view:

```
$newArray = urlencode(json_encode($array));
```

**OR:**

```
$.post('<?=base_url()?>controller/function/'+encodeURIComponent('<?=$newArray ?>')).done(function (res) {
        alert(res);
    });
```

and

```
$json = urldecode($urlencodedjson);
```

on the receiver side.

Answer (score 0):

In the view:

```
$newArray = json_encode($array)
$.post('<?=base_url()?>/controller/function',{t:<?=$newArray?>}).done(function (res) {
     alert(res);
});
```

In the controller:

```
$arr1 = $_POST['t'][0];
$arr1 = $_POST['t'][1];
```